# T-SQL delete cascade (or trigger) with multiple references to child table

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

The problem is larger, but this is it in a nutshell. I have two tables `Invoice` and `Address`.

The `Invoice` table has two columns:

- `BillingAddressId int`, FK to `Address(AddressId)`
- `ShippingAddressId int`, FK to `Address(AddressId)`

I would like to declare both of these relationships with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, but I can't because this causes the "multiple cascade paths" error.  I need to be able to delete the `Invoice` record and have it delete both `Address` records.

So instead, I create the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Invoice_DeleteAddress]
ON [dbo].[Invoice]
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NoCount ON

    DELETE FROM Address 
    WHERE AddressId IN (SELECT BillingAddressId FROM deleted);

    DELETE FROM Address 
    WHERE AddressId IN (SELECT InvoiceAddressId FROM deleted);
END
```

This flat out doesn't work, as now I get:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Invoice_BillingAddress".
>   The conflict occurred in database "Example", table "dbo.Invoice", column 'BillingAddressId'.

Also tried this suggestion:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Invoice_DeleteAddress]
ON [dbo].[Invoice]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NoCount ON

    DELETE FROM Address 
    WHERE AddressId IN (SELECT BillingAddressId FROM deleted);

    DELETE FROM Address 
    WHERE AddressId IN (SELECT InvoiceAddressId FROM deleted);

    DELETE FROM Invoice
    Where InvoiceId in (SELECT InvoiceID from deleted);

END
```

This has the same error.

What have I missed?

Comment: Is there any chance that you could change your database design such that the `adresss` primary key is not linked to two foreign keys in the same table?

Comment: In your schema one Address can be linked to several Invoices. So, when you delete an invoice you should be deleting its address only if it is not referenced by any other invoice.

Comment: @Tim: No, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you are trying to delete the parent automatically when you delete the child. This may not possible because the parent could be linked to another invoice. In any event it is not generally a good idea. You really need to revisit this requirement and see if it truly makes sense to do.  I have never seen a system (and I have worked with hundreds) where the deletion of a child automatically triggered the deletion of a parent record.

In this case it could be especially bad. If I were a customer and a I cancelled an invoice and went to buy a few days later and had to re-enter the address information I gave you previously, I would be annoyed and far less likely to want to continue to do business with a company foolish enough to do such a thing. This is the type of requirement that drives business away. Why on earth woudl you want to delete the address with the invoice? Why on earth would you be deleting invoices at all? Most accounting systems never ever delete invoices. If they need to cancel them, then they back them out with an offsetting charge. This whole idea could open up your system to fraud as no one person should ever be allowed to do such a thing, so it is really a bad idea. You really need to do some reading on accounting standards and especially on internal controls.

You can't delete the parent record until the child record is gone, this is why the triggers are not working for you.

I would suggest that you do all the deleting in a stored procedure or alternatively, have the trigger put the address ID records in a staging table and then delete them from a job that runs every five minutes. In this job, you would make sure to check to see if there are any other invoices attached to that address and only delete when there are none left. But still I think deleting either the addresses or the invoices is a truly bad idea.